# Windows 7 and nVidia 8400M G Problems

Tags: windows-7, drivers, nvidia-graphics-card

I've a LG E500 laptop with a nVidia 8400M G graphic card and after having tried the new Windows 7 RC on my EeePC I decided that I would install it also on this "work" laptop since I liked it so much.

The problem is that I'm having really bad time installing the drivers, I already downloaded a few versions from the nVidia website ([incluiding the newest driver: 186.03](http://us.download.nvidia.com/Windows/186.03/186.03_notebook_win7_32bit_international_whql.exe)), for Windows 7, Vista and XP but I get always the same message (I translated it, so it might not match the original error):

> Setup has not detected NVIDIA drivers
>   compatible with the current hardware.

Any pointers?

PS: I already run the Windows Update and downloaded all the avaliable updates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a while NVIDIA and ATI did not provide the drivers for download of the website, and these where only available from the manufacturers directly, however Nvidia recently released the M range drivers to the public. [Source](http://www.nvidia.com/object/notebook_drivers.html)

Make sure you download the specific drivers ending in M, and if you still have a problem you may need a modded INF since the notebook itself may not be supported by the standard installer. THe modded INF you can find at [LaptopVideo2Go](http://www.laptopvideo2go.com/)

Comment: You get kudos from me if you are sure changing the INF file will make the drivers work for the 8400M even if it's not officially supported!

Comment: @Ivo 2x Acer Notebooks, 1x Dell Notebook, 1x Alienware notebook. I have done this so many times I don't even think about it anymore. However it is not always gaurenteed. Some cards just refuse to be recognised

Comment: Then +1 assuming it's going to work for him, it sure is a better solution than I can offer: none :P

Comment: The 8400M driver for Windows 7 is available @ nVidia website, and I'm sure I already tried it. Can you give me some guidance on hacking the inf file?

Comment: Download the new one from LaptopVideo2Go for the Driver your trying to install, rename the current one and replace it with the new one. If I recall the detailed instructions is on the site as well when you download the INF. They also sometimes have premodded drivers on the site already. Also make sure your model is in the list for the driver you download.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same videocard in my old HP laptop and they always told me that the drivers for that type where supplied by the OEM client of Nvidia: HP in my case.

So unless LG supplies you with up to date drives, I think you can't get any better drivers...

Edit: I saw EEE so I assumed Asus, but off course your right

Comment: ASUS? It's weird because, I think, the hardware is the same. I visited the LG website but the only avaliable drivers they have are very old and for Windows XP / Vista.

Comment: Changed it :-) but I had the same problem only the original Vista drivers which sucked like hell

Answer (score 0):

I had until several days a go a lot of problems with my Notebook LG E500 with installed Windows 7 and nVidia 8400M G and after I have installed the software "**NVIDIA n Tune**" all the problems were solved.

At first place I have installed the NVIDIA driver version 296.10. Then after installing the "NVIDIA n Tune" software, I have run the program with the option "Tune System" which duration is about 20 minutes last. At last I have run in this software the "Execute the Stability Test" option. After reboot the PC, the "blue screen error" has disappeared until now.

Everything works well now!